# flutter : The input tensor should have dimensions 1 x height x width x 3. Got 1 x 3 x 416 x 416

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit, flutter-image

I'm trying to run custom tflite model in my mobile app  with the help of [google_mlkit_image_labeling](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_image_labeling) package, but I got this error :

**The input tensor should have dimensions 1 x height x width x 3. Got 1 x 3 x 416 x 416., null)**

```
  Future<void> processImage(InputImage inputImage) async {
    if (!_canProcess) return;
    if (_isBusy) return;
    _isBusy = true;
    setState(() {
      _text = '';
    });
 
      // probably something to do here to convert image from 1 x 3 x 416 x 416 to  1 x 416 x 416 x 3 
      // but I don't know how !!!
    final labels = await _imageLabeler.processImage(inputImage);
    print(labels.toString());
    _isBusy = false;
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

any idea how we can convert image or Uint8List in flutter to match pattern 1 x height x width x 3 instead of 1 x 3 x height x width